# Aviso de erro de sintaxe no console rodando AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

estou com o seguinte código, que usa factory:

```
angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);

.factory('factCliente', ['$http', function($http) {
var _getData2 = function(id_empresa) {
    return $http.post("php/index.php", id_empresa);
};

return {
    getData2: _getData2
}
}])

.controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, factCliente) {

//var id_empresa = {id: id_empresa};
var id_empresa = {id: 1};
factCliente.getData2(id_empresa).then(function(response) {
    $scope.mostraTodasContasEntradas = response;
}, function(error) {
    console.log("Ocorreu um erro: " + error);
});
});
```

E o aviso que aparece no console, é esse:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["
```

Código php:

```
<?php
    function mostraContasEntrada($id_empresa){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $pdo = conectar();
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada=$pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT c.categoria, sc.subcategoria, data, valor 
         FROM entrada e 
         JOIN cat_entradas c 
         on c.id_categoria = e.categoria 
         JOIN sub_cat_entrada sc 
         on sc.id_subcategoria 
         WHERE id_empresa=:id_empresa 
         ORDER BY data DESC");
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada->bindValue(":id_empresa", $id_empresa);
    $this->mostraDadosEntrada->execute();

    $return = array();

    while ($r = $this->mostraDadosEntrada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $dataP = explode("-", $r['data']);
        $data = $dataP[2].'/'.$dataP[1].'/'.$dataP[0];

        $r['data'] = $data;
        $r['valor'] = number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.');
        $r['subcategoria'] = utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']);
        $return[] = $r;

        //echo $data.'  '.$r['categoria'].'  '.utf8_encode($r['subcategoria']).'  '.number_format($r['valor'],2,',','.')."<br>";

        echo json_encode($return);
    }

    }
<?
```

Chamada da classe e função:

```
require_once "../con/conexao.php";
require_once "../classes/contaEntrada.php";
require_once "../classes/contaSaida.php";

$entrada = new contaEntrada();
$saidas = new contaSaida();

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$id_empresa = $request->id_empresa;

$entrada->mostraContasEntrada($id_empresa);
```

Alguém sabe que problema, que erro de sintaxe, é esse?

Comment: Poste o erro completo, mas ainda assim verifique os fechamentos de chave e parênteses. Inicialmente ele tem um colchete "[" abrindo em um lugar errado. Faça bom uso da indentação e chame angular module novamente quando puder.

Comment: Como diz o console é erro de sintaxe. Se você tem alguma ideia de onde ocorre o erro, ovcê pode [debugar](http://www.devmedia.com.br/depurando-javascript-com-google-chrome/28367) o código pelo navegador.

Comment: Já procurei por um outro colchete que possa estar aberto e não fechado, mas não encontrei. você mesmo pode procurar, pois todo o meu código está, aqui, no post.

Comment: Seu retorno JSON pode ser inválido, como apontado pela exceção no console. Pode postar um exemplo?

Comment: Coloquei aqui no posta o código.

Comment: Algumas coisas que notei analisando seu código. Seu PHP possui alguns errinhos de syntax, como o fechamento da tag `<?` sendo que deveria ser `?>` e alguns colchetes fora do lugar. Recomendo verificar bem o fechamento de tudo, pois um erro no php pode anular todo o seu javascript, mesmo sem estar executando a função diretamente. Outra coisa, coloque um `console.log(mostraTodasContasEntradas)` no fim do seu controller para ver o que o php está retornando, as vezes é um erro de lógica do php e não do AngularJs. Busque sempre um debug dos resultados com console para entender o problema. =D

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, só aqui eu coloquei o fechamento da tag php. No meu código mesmo, não coloquei.

Comment: `var id_empresa = {id: id_empresa}` Esse valor, ele vem de onde? E está sendo gerado como?

Comment: Celso, coloquei o console.log(mostraTodasContasEntrada) e apareceu isso:

(id_empresa) {
  console.log('id da empresa '+id_empresa);
 $http.get("php/index.php?action=mostraContasEntrada(id_empresa)").then(
  function(data) {
   $scope.contas = data;
   //console.lo…

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, na verdade eu estou colocando na mão esse id_empresa, pois não não criei a session, estou só testando.

Comment: Se você usar o console, como comentei, que resultado irá obter? Não o erro que aparece diretamente no console, mas sim o retorno que você chama inserindo o console.log no controller. Assim vamos saber se o json está vindo com erro ou nao. Acredito que o problema seja o seu retorno php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque o **$http.post** retornar uma promise e não os dados propriamente dito. Para acessar o retorno você precisa passar dois métodos para outro que está na promise chamado **then**. O primeiro método recebe o dado em si. Já o segundo recebe um objeto de erro caso esse tenha acontecido.

Para exemplificar:

A variável **mostraTodasContasEntradas** deve estar sendo usada em parte do teu código para exibir uma lista certo? No teu código ele está recebendo uma promise e não uma estrutura de array. Veja o exemplo corrigido abaixo e observe essa parte: **factCliente.getData2(id_empresa).then**

```
angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);

angular.module("fluxo").config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/entradas", {
        templateUrl: "views/entradas.html",
        controller: "fluxoCtrl"
    })
    .when("/saidas", {
        templateUrl: "views/saidas.html",
        controller: "fluxoCtrl"
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: "/index"});
})

.factory('factCliente', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _getData2 = function(id_empresa) {
        return $http.post("php/index.php", id_empresa);
    };

    return {
        getData2: _getData2
    }
}])

.controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, factCliente) {
    var id_empresa = {id: id_empresa};
    factCliente.getData2(id_empresa).then(function(response) {
        $scope.mostraTodasContasEntradas = response;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Ocorreu um erro: " + error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31508/discussion-on-answer-by-emir-marques-aviso-de-erro-de-sintaxe-no-console-rodando)

Answer (score 2):

Modifiquei a parte

```
return {
    getData2: _getData2,
}
```

para

```
return {
    getData2: _getData2
};
```

Removi a última vírgula e adicionei um ponto e vírgula. No JSlint passou (adicionando a variável angular e marcando a opção messy white space).

Ele questiona a variável id_empresa fora de escopo e algumas variáveis não utilizadas.

```
'use strict';

angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);

angular.module("fluxo").config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when("/entradas", {
        templateUrl: "views/entradas.html",
        controller: "fluxoCtrl"
    })

    .when("/saidas", {
        templateUrl: "views/saidas.html",
        controller: "fluxoCtrl"
    })

    .otherwise({redirectTo: "/index"});

})

.factory('factCliente', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getClientes: function(id_empresa) {
            return $http.post("php/index," id_empresa)
        }
    };
}])

.controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, factCliente) {
    $scope.clientes = [];

    var consultaClientes = function(data, status) {
        $scope.clientes = data;
    };

    factCliente.getClientes().success(consultaClientes);
});
```

Comment: Não entendi, qual a sua sugestão?
Eu fiz uma modificação que vc falou:

return { getData2: _getData2 };

É só isso? Pois o aviso continua.

Comment: Testei no jslint ele não acusou mais erros.

Comment: Pois é, to achando muito estranho, pois parece estar tudo certo!

Comment: Você conhece outra maneira de criar uma função em angular que chame uma função em uma classe em php?

Comment: Sim, o uso do módulo ngResource desde que seu php retorne um JSON.

Comment: Como seria? E como posso te passar meu código php para vc ver?

Comment: Pode sim. Poste seu código e podemos analisar.

Comment: Postei meu php.

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido de colocar, aqui, como estou chamada a classe e a função da classe